# LINQ2SQL Stack overflow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I am getting a stack overflow with the following code. I know what the problem is, that it executes all "GetAllPages" in the

```
           Children = new LazyList<Page>(from p in GetAllPages(language)
                                         where p.ParentPage == s.Id
                                         select p)
```

before it adds the p.ParentPage == s.Id

```
private IQueryable<Page> GetAllPages(string language)
{
    return from s in context.Pages
           where (from c in GetAllContent()
                  where c.PageId == s.Id &&
                        c.Language.ToLower() == language.ToLower()
                  select c).Any()

           let contents = (from c in GetAllContent()
                           where c.PageId == s.Id
                           select c)
           select new Page()
           {
               Id = s.Id,
               SiteId = s.SiteId,
               Type = s.Type,
               Template = s.Template,
               ParentPage = s.ParentPage,
               Visible = s.Visible,
               Order = s.Order,

               Contents = contents.ToList(),
               Children = new LazyList<Page>(from p in GetAllPages(language)
                                             where p.ParentPage == s.Id
                                             select p)
           };
}
```

How can i do this, correctly?

UPDATE:
The reason behind the code is that, i have a tree structured menu, where one menu item can have 0 to many child items.
The language part can be skipped, but my site support multiple languages, and with the language parameters do i only want menu items there have a content of the given language.

Comment: I can understand the problem, but don't understand the context behind the code. Can you please explain what the code is trying to do, and why you require recursion?

Comment: Just updated my post with more info

Comment: I have made a temp fix, by creating a clone function that takes parentid as the argument. but i would prefer not to have duplicated data :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the moment that you call this `GetAllPages(language)`, and then call it again with out change the `language` you get 100% stack overflow.

You need to get something that is different, not the same ! and your only parameter is the `language` and this is not change.

```
private IQueryable<Page> GetAllPages(string language)
{
 ....
   Children = new LazyList<Page>(from p in GetAllPages(language) // <-- here you 
          // call him self again with the same parametre.
          // Your function is going to call him self asking the same think
          //  This is bring the stack overflow
          //  When you make call to the same function you need some how
          //   to get different results with some different parameter.
```